# Detect when Marketo embed form has been loaded via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, marketo

Is there a way to detect when a Marketo form has successfully loaded when you embed it in your HTML page?

I want to manipulate the form with jQuery, but it is not always loaded when the .ready() event fires.

Answer (score 2):

Marketo Forms 2.0 provides a method called whenReady, which allows you to specify a callback function when the Marketo Form reaches its ready event. So you can use this method to notify the client when the Marketo Form has loaded.

Please see the [Marketo developer documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Marketo Forms 2.0 **`.loadForm`** method allows for a **callback** as its fourth argument. Just add in your function there.

**From the [API Reference](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0#api-reference)**

```
.loadForm(baseUrl, munchkinId, formId [,callback])
```

**Example**

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjqe.marketo.com", "718-GIV-198", 621, function(form){
    //from here we have access to the form object and can call its methods.
});
```

If you use `.whenReady(callback)`, if *'there is already a form that is ready at the time this function is called, the passed callback will be called immediately'*, which might not be what you want.

(@Murtza works at Marketo, so maybe his answer is more official, but it didn't work for me)